# mod_rewrite rule to check if file exists on server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a mod_rewrite rule and I can't figure it out myself.

The request URL can be:

```
https://image.domain.com/sub.domain.com/400x400/image.jpg
```

In `.htaccess` I want to check if the following file exists:

```
/sub.domain.com/cache/400x400/image.jpg
```

If this file exists, than it should serve the file. If not exist, then continue to the next mod_rewrite rule.

Is this possible with mod_rewrite? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `sub.domain.com/.htaccess` if it doesn't exist with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ignore files and directories from all rewrite rules    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (^|/)index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub.domain.com/cache/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(?!cache/)(.+\.\w+)$ cache/$1 [L,NC]

#Else go to controller
RewriteRule ^(|(.*)/)([0-9]+x[0-9]+|[a-z]+[0-9]+|original)/(.*)$ ../index.php?path=$4&format=$3&folder=sub.domain.com [L,QSA]
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?!cache/)` - negative lookahead to ignore requests that already have `cache/`
- `(.+\.\w+)` - Match any request with at least an extension and captures it in `$1`
- 1st rule has 2 `RewriteCond` that checks if request is NOT for an existing file or directory
- 2nd `RewriteCond` checks presence of `$1` file using full path in `cache/` directory
- If condition succeeds then in the target we just prefix the relative file path with `cache/`

Comment: This seems to work. Can you explain the RewriteRule? I need to change it so it will also work with png, gif etc. Maybe even every file extension.

Comment: I've added explanation and also modified rule to support any extension.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I added this line next below your rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule ^(|(.*)\/)([0-9]+x[0-9]+|[a-z]+[0-9]+|original)\/(.*)$ ../index.php?path=$4&format=$3&folder=sub.domain.com [L,QSA]`

but now it always catches this rule, even if the file exists.

Comment: Check my edit. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should skip that.

Comment: That doesn't work, it keeps being rewritten to `../index.php`.

Comment: You should paste your full content from `sub.domain.com/.htaccess`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128479/discussion-between-timo002-and-anubhava).